# Hadoop YARN can't start resource manager from data nodes (Ubuntu 16.04 on EC2)

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, amazon-ec2, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to build a Hadoop cluster on 4 nodes using AWS EC2s, all Ubuntu 16.04.

Everything seems to work fine, and the log files don't produce any errors while formatting namenode or running `start-dfs.sh` and `start-yarn.sh`

But when I try to upload a file to HDFS, the datanodes seem to have problems connecting to the resource manager. The generic error on the namenode tells me that there are 0 nodes running and the log files of the data nodes tell me:

```
INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Registering with RM using containers :[]
INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ip-10-0-0-190.eu-central-1.compute.internal/10.0.0.190:8025. Already tried 0 time(s); maxRetries=45
```

It points towards the private ip address of the namenode (10-0-0-190), a different EC2 instance in the same VPC.

The yarn-site.xml looks the same for every node (both data and name node), all pointing towards the namenode:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  ...
-->
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
        <value>10.0.0.190:8025</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
        <value>10.0.0.190:8030</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
        <value>10.0.0.190:8050</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I can't find what I'm doing wrong, and I find it difficult to tell what goes wrong, based on these log errors/warnings.

Help is highly appreciated! I can provide more details/logs/configuration details if needed.

Comment: Can you connect from data nodes to a namenode? `telnet 10.0.0.190 8025`

Comment: Thx Sergey, I don't get any response when running the command. Servers are only accessible by SSH, port 22. Does this mean that I should adjust firewall settings for the namenode, even though they are within the same VPC? And does this mean I should open many more ports? What about security?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction: I did not configure the firewall in the right way. You should open all (relevant) inbound trafic between servers within the Hadoop network. When you use AWS, go to Security Groups and allow all TCP from your security group.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated the /etc/hosts file in data nodes? Also run jps command on data nodes to see if they are running.

Comment: thx for your reply. jps is giving back: `26053 Jps, 25615 DataNode, 25743 NodeManager`. hosts looks like: 
`10.0.0.190 hadoop-master`
`10.0.0.190 hadoop-snn`
`10.0.0.83 hadoop-slave-1`
`10.0.0.244 hadoop-slave-2`
`10.0.0.185 hadoop-slave-3` on all nodes

Comment: Can you try using port 8032 instead of 8050 for yarn.resourcemanager.address property?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction: I did not configure the firewall in the right way. You should open all (relevant) inbound trafic between servers within the Hadoop network. When you use AWS, go to Security Groups and allow all TCP from your security group.